# Dynamic convert qspinbox to qdoublespinbox

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox, qdoublespinbox

I have a qspinbox which use int values only. Also i have checkbox. If checkbox == 0, qspinbox must use int values only, but if checkbox == 1, qspinbox must use float values only. Is It possible? Maybe it is possible with qdoublespinbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a QDoubleSpinBox. When the checkbox is not checked, set the precision of the spinbox to 0. You do that by setting the [decimals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#decimals-prop) property.

You might also need to change the [singleStep](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#singleStep-prop) property if you're not using the default (which is 1.0).

Comment: It was easier than I thought. Thank you <3